# Prove this square matrix has no square root

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove the matrix with filled with 0s everywhere except 1s just above the main diagonal has no square root.
The matrix looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziJ5n.png)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

(Fill in the gaps as needed. If you're stuck, show your work and explain why you're stuck.)

**Hint:** Prove that the minimal polynomial is $ A^{n} = 0 $.

---

Do a proof by contradiction.
Suppose $ A = B^2$.
Then, ...

---

More generally, the minimal polynomial contains $A^k = 0 $ where $ k > n/2$ as a factor, then $A$ has no square root.

Comment: @WillJagy Can you add that as a separate solution? Mine reduces to $ A^ {\lceil n/2 \rceil} = 0 $, which seems distinct from yours.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite visual. The main trick is that $M^2 $ and $M$ always commute, as associativity
$$ M M^2 =  M (M M) = (M M) M = M^2 M $$
Therefore, assuming $M^2 = J$ where $J$ is the matrix given, we know that $JM = MJ$

I will display intermediate steps for dimension $4.$

$$
J = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0&1&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
0&0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
$$
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a&b&c&d \\
e&f&g&h \\
i&j&k&l \\
m&n&o&p \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
JM = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
e&f&g&h \\
i&j&k&l \\
m&n&o&p \\
0&0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
MJ = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0&a&b&c \\
0&e&f&g \\
0&i&j&k \\
0&m&n&o \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Equating the two matrices gives
$$  e=i=m=n=o= 0$$
which then leads to
$$  j=e=0  $$
Next $$ a=f=k=p$$
which are permitted nonzero for now.
Then $$ b=g=l$$
and finally $$ c = h$$
$$
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
a&b&c&d \\
0&a&b&c \\
0&0&a&b \\
0&0&0&a \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
That is as far as commutativity takes us. Now we explicitly demand $M^2 = J$
The $(1,1)$ position in $M^2$ is calculated as $a^2$ (because of all the zero entries). Therefore, $M^2 = J$ tells us that

$$
M = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
0&b&c&d \\
0&0&b&c \\
0&0&0&b \\
0&0&0&0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

is strictly upper triangular.

However, we now see that the $(1,2) $ position in $M^2$ is equal to $0,$ which contradicts the fact that the entry of $J$ in the $(1,2)$ position is set to $1.$

The idea of commuting with a nilpotent Jordan block was in my mind as I had left a comment at

[commutes with a nilpotent matrix and invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929225/commutes-with-a-nilpotent-matrix-and-invertible)

The theorem on commuting with Jordan blocks is this: if a square matrix $M$ has just a single Jordan block for each eigenvalue, the only possible matrices that commute with it are polynomials in $M,$  that is
$$ aI + b M + c M^2 + \cdots + z M^{n-1}  $$