# Proving that $\det(A+N) = 0$ with N a nilpotent matrix and A a singular matrix such that AN=NA

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, nilpotence

> Let $N \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be a nilpotent matrix of indice $m$ and $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ a matrix such that $A N=N A$.
> We assume that $A$ is singular. Expressing $(A+N)^{k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, prove that $\det(A+N) = 0$.

I don't know how to prove this using binomial formula, i can't pursue because of the $A^{k}$ in the formula and the non linearity of the determinant for matrix. I found an explanation in a previous topic but they used the trace and the newton's identity to prove that the characteristic polynomial of A+N and A is the same. What i have not understood is how to apply the newton's identities and the trace.

Comment: This is false for $A = I_n$. Maybe you are meant to prove that $\det\left(A+N\right) = 1$ ?

Comment: More likely, that $\det(A+N) = \det(A)$.

Comment: I presume this is the previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929225/commutes-with-a-nilpotent-matrix-and-invertible/

Comment: @darijgrinberg yes now you tell it, it is true that there is a problem when A=I.. certainly there is a mistake in the exercise

Comment: I have made a mistake. A is supposed singular. @darijgrinberg

Comment: I don't understand how you used newton identies in the topic you answered @user8675309

Comment: working over $\mathbb C$ makes this relatively easy:  for an $m\times m$ matrix $X$, you have $\text{trace}\big(X^k\big) = \sum_{j=1}^m \lambda_j^k$, i.e. a power (/Newton) sum in the roots (eigenvalues) of the characteristic polynomial.  Newton's Identities allow you to recover the characteristic polynomial from these first $m$ traces.  Thus if two $m\times m$ matrices $Y$ and $Z$ satisfy $\text{trace}\big(Y^k\big) = \text{trace}\big(Z^k\big)$ for $1\leq k\leq m$, then they have the same characteristic polynomial.  And same characteristic polynomial of course implies same determinant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pick any nonzero vector $x\in\ker(A)$. Then
\begin{aligned}
(A+N)^nx
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}N^{n-k}A^kx\quad\text{(because $AN=NA$)}\\
&=N^nx\quad\text{(because $Ax=0$)}\\
&=0.\quad\text{(because $N^n=0$)}.
\end{aligned}
Therefore $(A+N)^n$ is singular. In turn, $A+N$ is singular.

Comment: What happens if x is not in ker(A)? And it seems you have not used the hypothesis that A is singular. In fact, if A=I, det(I+N)=det(I)=1 which is different from 0 @user1551

Comment: @MouhamadouMoustapha $x$ is **chosen** from $\ker(A)$. It exists precisely because $A$ is singular.

Comment: Yes i understand now. As A is singular, det(A)=0 or again det(A-0.I)=0. Thus 0 is an eighenvalue for A: it exists a nonzero vector x such that Ax=0. Then it comes that (A+N)^n.x=0. But a linear application is regular if and only if its nullspace is reduced to the zero vector... Thanks a lot @user1551