# Common Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given is a matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ and corresponding eigenvector $v$. Choose an arbitrary vector $b\in \mathbb{R}^n$, show that $B=A+vb^t$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$.

I was given the hint to consider $\mu\neq \lambda+ b^tv$, as $Bv=(\lambda+ b^tv)v $, and find eigenvectors of the form $w+cv$, where $c$ is a scalar and $Aw=\mu w$.

Edit:
After playing around with traces for a bit, a arrived at the following. Let $\nu_i$ be the eigenvalues of $B$ and
$mu_i$ be the eigenvalues of $A$. Further let wlog
$\mu_1 = \lambda$:
$$
\mathrm{trace}(B) = \sum_{i=1}^n \nu_i = \sum_{i=1}^nb_{ii} = 
\sum_{i=1}^n(a_{ii} + v_ib_i) = \sum_{i=1}^na_{ii} + b^tv\\
=\sum_{i=2}^n\mu_i + \lambda + b^tv
$$

Comment: The statement is certainly false. Consider the case where $A=0$ and $b^tv\ne0$. Then all eigenvalues of $A$ are zero and $B$ has a nonzero eigenvalue because it has a nonzero trace.

Comment: But if $b$ is orthogonal to $v$, then $B$ can still be non-zero but $\mathrm{trace}(B) = \mathrm{trace}(vb^t) =  \mathrm{trace}(b^tv) = 0$

Answer (score 0):

The claim holds true *iff* $\text{trace}\big(\mathbf v\mathbf b^T\big)  =0$.  Necessity should be obvious (and is stated in the comments).

**Solution 1:**
For sufficiency: it is enough to prove this when $\lambda =0$ (i.e. consider $A':= A-\lambda I$ if needed).  Structurally the proof is very similar to the one I gave here: [commutes with a nilpotent matrix and invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3929225/commutes-with-a-nilpotent-matrix-and-invertible/) though a little uglier.

We have equality of characteristic polynomials $p_A(t)=p_{A+\mathbf {vb}^T}(t)$ because
$\text{trace}\big(A+\mathbf {vb}^T\big)=\text{trace}\big(A\big)+\text{trace}\big(\mathbf {vb}^T\big)=\text{trace}\big(A\big)$

and for $k \in \big\{2,3, \dots, n\big\}$
$\text{trace}\Big(\big(A+\mathbf {vb}^T\big)^k\Big)=\text{trace}\Big(A^k\Big)+\text{trace}\Big(\big(\mathbf {vb}^T\big)^k\Big)+\text{trace}\Big(\text{Cross Terms}\Big)=\text{trace}\Big(A^k\Big)$
since $\big(\mathbf {vb}^T\big)^k=\mathbf 0$ and each cross term involves a mixed product of $A$ and $\mathbf {vb}^T$, every single one of which must be $=\mathbf 0$ with the exception of those of the form $\big(\mathbf {vb}^T\big)^r A^{k-r}$ which are traceless because
$\text{trace}\Big(\big(\mathbf {vb}^T\big)^r A^{k-r}\Big)= \text{trace}\Big(\big(\mathbf {vb}^T\big)^{r-1} A^{k-r-1}A\mathbf {vb}^T\Big)=0$ since $A\mathbf {vb}^T=\big(A\mathbf v\big)\mathbf b^T = \mathbf 0\mathbf b^t =\mathbf 0$

conclude $p_A(t)=p_{A+\mathbf {vb}^T}(t)$ by Newton's Identities

**Solution 2:**
work over $\mathbb C$ and do Schur Triangularization with $\alpha \mathbf q_1 = \mathbf v$ (i.e. normalized $\mathbf v$) we have
$A=QRQ^*$ or $AQ=QR$
and with standard basis vector $\mathbf e_1$ we have
$\mathbf v\mathbf b^TQ = \mathbf v\big(\mathbf b^TQ\big)=\mathbf v\mathbf y^T =\alpha \mathbf q_1\mathbf y^T=\alpha Q\mathbf e_1\mathbf y^T$
where $0=\text{trace}\big( Q^*\mathbf v\mathbf b^TQ\big)=\text{trace}\big(\mathbf e_1\mathbf y^T\big) = y_1$
so $\alpha\mathbf e_1\mathbf y^T$ is upper triangular with all zeros on the diagonal.

Conclude $A + \mathbf v\mathbf b^T = Q\big(R+\alpha\mathbf e_1\mathbf y^T\big)Q^*$
and in particular $R+\alpha\mathbf e_1\mathbf y^T$ is upper triangular with the same diagonal elements as $R$ hence the eigenvalues are the same.